# Sorting and filtering options for Playlists Endpoint

Tags: deezer

I can't see sorting params for playlists/tracks endpoint of Deezer API. I want to list playlist tracks by creation date or filter only if `is_loved` is false. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is no sorting parameter directly usable in the API request, you can only play with the limit and offset. You have to sort the result yourself.